# Datepicker is not working in iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, datepicker

I am working on one phonegap application. I am using datepicker tag which is working fine on Andriod and window devices but in iphone it behaves strange. whenever i am trying to select year it selects any random year.
Pleas check the below code :

```
<datepicker datepicker-toggle="true" date-max-limit="{{ todaysDate.toString() }}" 
date-set="{{ selectedPet.age.toString() }}" 
date-format="MMM dd, yyyy"> 
<input ng-model="selectedPet.age" name="age" type="text" ng-required="true" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0E75DE; background: #fafafa; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 15px; width: 100%;" size="32" /> 
</datepicker>
```

[image]

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your date-max-limit is also not worked.
Please try this ::

```
<datepicker datepicker-toggle="true"  
  date-max-limit="{{ todaysDate.toString() |date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" 
  date-min-limit="1950"
  date-set="{{ selectedPet.age.toString() }}"   
  date-format="MMM dd, yyyy">

   <input ng-model="selectedPet.age" name="age" type="text" ng-     
   required="true" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0E75DE;  background:    
   #fafafa; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px; height: 50px; margin-bottom:  
   15px; width: 100%;" size="32" />
</datepicker>
```